# Do you need to call LibGDX's dispose?

Tags: java, libgdx

The LibGDX Actor does not have a dispose method, though it has a texture. Do I need to call dispose on its texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `dispose()` when you no longer need the resource. This is to free up the memory that the resource had been using. So yes, you need to call dispose when you're finished using your object.

Comment: Does this apply to the Actor's texture? The Actor class itself does not have a dispose method to call.

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, this applies to all resources that can be disposed. Texture can be disposed so it should be disposed.